# Assign number input to number variable?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Typescript is telling me that type string is not assignable to type number.

How can I make Typescript happy?

Two voluntary related questions:

What is a good way to learn what TypeScript types I should use for various callback arguments? I had to google to find that `React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>`  is the type I am expected to use for html events

Why does typescript assume string for event.currentTarget.value?

```
interface SoftwareLicenseCodesState {
    duration: number,
}

<input
    type="number"
    value={this.state.duration}
    onChange={this.onDurationChange}
/>

onDurationChange(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement> ): void {
    this.setState({duration: event.currentTarget.value});
}
```

Comment: The `value` of an `input` is always a string. To get a number, parse it -- or if the browser supports the "HTML5" `type=number` field, use `valueAsNumber`.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem